# Typecasting in Swift

Tags: ios, types, casting, swift

I am writing a library which can parse typed Ids from JSON. However, I am finding the typecasting rules a little baffling.

Example:

```swift
class AccountId : NSString { }

let json : AnyObject? = "user-1" // Returned by NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData
let s = json as? NSString   // Succeeds, s == Some("user-1")
let a = json as? AccountId  // Fails, a == nil
```

Why does the first typecast succeed while the second one fail? Is there something magical about `NSString` which does not crossover to Swift-only classes?

I am using XCode Version 6.1 (6A1030) (the latest at the time of writing).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have a hierarchy of classes A -> B -> C (C inherits from B, which in turn inherits from A), and you have an instance of B, you can upcast to A, but you cannot downcast to C.

The reason is that C might add properties which are not available in B, so the compiler or the runtime wouldn't know how to initialize the additional data, not to mention that it must also be allocated.

Note that polymorphism allows you do to upcast and downcast with variables - which means, if you have an instance of C stored in a variable of type A, you can cast that variable to B and C, because it actually contains an instance of C. But if the variable contains an instance of B, you can downcast to B, but not to C.

In your case, rather than downcasting you should specialize a constructor accepting `NSString`,  but I suspect that in this specific case of `NSString` it cannot be done (there's no `NSString` designated initializer accepting a string as argument). If you are able to do that, then your code would look like:

```
var json: AnyObject? = "test"
if let string = json as? NSString {
    let a = AccountId(string: string)
}
```

and at that point you can use `a` where an instance of either `AccountId` or `NSString` is expected

Comment: So there is no way to do this for `NSString` or can I create a new constructor only in the `AccountId` class (with different arguments than any `NSString` constructor) which can do it? Is there no way I can create instances of `AccountId` class?

Comment: I'a afraid you can't. However I think that inheriting a class from NSString just to provide a different semantic is not a good practice in my personal opinion - it's still a string with no added value. I don't know if you need compilation type check - if not, than you may look into [typealias](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_481)

Comment: Yes, I was aiming for type-safety, much like [newtypes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype). I have been using typealiases to work around this. They help in readability a little bit but lack the type-safety features. Thanks for the answer and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something magical about NSString which does not crossover to Swift-only classes?

**Yes.** Swift's `String` class is automatically bridged to `NSString` and vice versa. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_41):

> Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString
>   class. This means that anywhere you use an NSString object, you can
>   use a Swift String type instead and gain the benefits of both
>   types—the String type’s interpolation and Swift-designed APIs and the
>   NSString class’s broad functionality. For this reason, you should
>   almost never need to use the NSString class directly in your own code.
>   In fact, when Swift imports Objective-C APIs, it replaces all of the
>   NSString types with String types. When your Objective-C code uses a
>   Swift class, the importer replaces all of the String types with
>   NSString in imported API.
>
> Why does the first typecast succeed while the second one failed?

Because of the strong relationship between `String` and `NSString`, the compiler knows how to convert from one to the other. On the other hand, because your `AccountId` class is a more specialized version of `NSString`, you can't cast from `String` to `AccountId`.

Comment: Thanks for the lucid answer. Is it possible to bridge this gap by, say , providing smart constructors on the `AccountId` class? Or, as @Antonio pointed out, is it nigh impossible with the `NSString` subclass?