# How to type cast in swift language

Tags: swift, types, casting

Please let me know how to type cast in Swift language.

```
[(FXImageView *)view setImageWithContentsOfURL:[items objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: Well explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typecasting in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104487/typecasting-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

That code should translate to something like

```
let view = FXImageView(imageWithContensOfURL(items[index]))
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: wouldn't this try to call the function FXImageView()?

Answer (score 0):

There is three keyword for typecasting in swift.

First one is `as`. It is used for the situations like casting from subclass to superclass. If you are using `as` for typecasting it is checked at compile time to guarantee casting is never failed. So its use pretty limited. Here is a sample:

```
class SuperClass {}

class SubClass: SuperClass {}

let a = SubClass()
let b = a as SuperClass
```

The second one is `as?`. It works basically like this. If casting is succeeded it returns an `Optional.Some<YourType>(yourObject)` and if it is failed it returns `Optional<YourType>.None` (etc `nil`). Here is a sample:

```
let someValue = 20
if let castedValue = someValue as? String {
    print("casting successfull. The value is \(castedValue)")
} else {
    print("casting failed")
}
```

Here obviously casting from `Int` to `String` will fail and `else` part will be executed.

The third one is `as!`. Its use case is similar to `as?`. If casting is successful you will get implicitly unwrapped optional and if it is failed your program will crash (as with other operations includes `!`.). Here is a sample use

```
let someValue = 20
let castedValue = someValue as! String
```

You should only use this one if you are sure the casting operation will always be successful. For your code I would write it like this

```
if let imageView = view as? FXImageView {
    imageView.setImageWithContentsOfURL(items[index])
} else {
    // handle the fail part
}
```

Or with `map` method on `Optional`

```
(view as? FXImageView).map { $0.setImageWithContentsOfURL(items[index]) }
```