# Typecasting a superview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I have subclassed a UIView, and I am trying to access it's superview, but it is returned as a UIView instead of the type of my subclass.

Here is a Swift 4 Playground showing an oversimplification of the problem.

```
import UIKit

class SubUIView: UIView {}

var parent:SubUIView = SubUIView()
var child:SubUIView = SubUIView()
parent.addSubview(child)
var other:SubUIView = child.superview
```

How can I typecast child.superview into a SubUIView?

Currently, it throws this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIView?' to specified type 'SubUIView'

Previous Stakeoverflow answers on this topic were not clear to me, but the answer provided here was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typecasting in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104487/typecasting-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`superview` is a property on `UIView` that your view subclass inherits. If you want to cast the view returned from the call to `superview` you have mainly two options:

Force casting, where `other`'s type will be `SubUIView`. If this operation fails – i.e. the super view isn't actually of type `SubUIView`, the application will crash. This is done with:

```
var other = child.superview as! SubUIView
```

You can also use `as?` instead of `as!`. This way the type for `other` will be `SubUIView?`, and if the casting fails, the value will be nil.

If you add type annotation to other, it'll have to match the result of the casting operation. As in:

```
var other: SubUIView = child.superview as! SubUIView
var other: SubUIView? = child.superview as? SubUIView
```

The type annotations are not needed though.

Comment: Good, complete answer. (Voted)

Comment: Cezar - That worked, and thanks for educating me beyond just my initial answer.  I really appreciate it.

Stackoverflow is now suggesting that this was covered in other questions, and after having read your answer, they do apply, but I read them before and they didn't help without your explanation.

Comment: @cdeerinck glad I could help :)